# Как отключиться от репозитория?

Tags: github

Добавился в учебный репозиторий и теперь не могу выйти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В watching их нет, в subscribtions тоже нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В списках репозиториев - тоже нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это просто список репозиториев, в которых вы недавно участвовали. Отключаться никак не нужно (вы не "подключены"), они просто постепенно опустятся в списке, по мере вашего участия в других репозиториях.

Comment: Спасибо большое